# Simplexml xpath formula not working

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I can not make work the formula in xpath. Here is a part of code to **reproduce the issue**:

```
//$val['path_xml'] = "price + 1"
$valID = $result[$i]->xpath($val['path_xml']);
echo "<br>".$val['path_xml']."<br>";
echo $result[$i]->price."<br>";
echo json_encode($valID)."<br>";
```

The output of the code is:

```
price + 1   // as expected - the correct path
525000      // just for test to check if price exists
[]          // empty array????
```

**Test 2** - just to make sure everything works fine:

```
//$val['path_xml'] = "price"
$valID = $result[$i]->xpath($val['path_xml']);
echo "<br>".$val['path_xml']."<br>";
echo $result[$i]->price."<br>";
echo json_encode($valID)."<br>";
```

Output:

```
price             // correct
525000            // ok
[{"0":"525000"}]  // OK
```

Can someone give any idea why the formulas are not working? Maybe need a newer version of PHP (currently 5.6) or any other ideas?

Checked it with this online tool and it works perfectly: http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: [XPath can find `price+1`](http://xpathfiddle.net/LNZT5Z) but on php not all XPath functions are implemented, so you can't use `price+1`. Updating PHP [doesn't change it](https://3v4l.org/KGDsW).

Comment: @fusion3k Thank you for your comment!! It seems like you are totally right! Please add this as an Answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer by fusion3k: XPath can find price+1 but on php not all XPath functions are implemented, so you can't use price+1. Updating PHP doesn't change it.